# Cannot run default JS script from within Remix?

Tags: remix, javascript, console, cli

just getting started with Remix.

I want to run the default deploy_ethers.js script and see there are two ways to do it:

1. Right-click on the script and hit "Run".
2. Open the file and run remix.exeCurrent() in the console.

When I try (1), I don't see anything occur. When I try (2), I get an error message in the console:

`scriptRunner plugin is already rendered`

Additionally, when I run `remix.help()`, I get an error: `remix.help is not a function`.

[image: console output]

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

FYI running using the JavascriptVM in Firefox on Ubuntu. And when I open developer tools I can see the following error log:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: scriptRunner plugin is already rendered
    render https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:206466
    connect https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:206417
    activate https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:206809
    __awaiter https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:3038
    __awaiter https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:3034
    activate https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:206805
    activatePlugin https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:207166
    fulfilled https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:3035
    promise callback*step https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:3037
    fulfilled https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:3035
    promise callback*step https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:3037
    __awaiter https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:3038
    __awaiter https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:3034
    activatePlugin https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:207135
    engineActivatePlugin https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:207267
    toggle https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:207589
    fulfilled https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:3035
    promise callback*step https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:3037
    __awaiter https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:3038
    __awaiter https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:3034
    toggle https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:207575
    toggleActive https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:207597
    __awaiter https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:3038
    __awaiter https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:3034
    toggleActive https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:207574
    callMethod https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:207054
    fulfilled https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:3035
    promise callback*step https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:3037
    fulfilled https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:3035
    promise callback*step https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:3037
    fulfilled https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:3035
    promise callback*step https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:3037
    fulfilled https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:3035
    promise callback*step https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:3037
    __awaiter https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:3038
    __awaiter https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:3034
    callMethod https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:207038
    call https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:207157
    runScript https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:413719
    get https://remix.ethereum.org/main.js:102350
    i https://remix.ethereum.org/assets/js/browserfs.min.js:7
    close https://remix.ethereum.org/assets/js/browserfs.min.js:7
    i https://remix.ethereum.org/assets/js/browserfs.min.js:7
```